# Como posso fazer uma roleta em Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom a minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu tenho um formulário em HTML, que ao carregar em submit ele da-me um número aleatório de 1 a 5 em PHP. O que eu queria saber era, como poderia fazer para que com que clicasse no botão o PHP selecionava um dos números 1 a 5 aleatoriamente e depois enviava para uma simples roleta em javascript para mostrar o numero escolhido. Ou seja a roleta simulava que rodava e calhava no número escolhido.

Comment: Gonçalo, bem vindo ao site. Evite de criar novas perguntas só pra receber mais atenção, se precisar alterar alguma coisa é só clicar no botão `editar` logo abaixo da sua pergunte. Visite o [tour do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para mais informações.

Comment: Não sei se é bem isto que queres (efeito tipo slot machine), mas pode ser útil. [Roulette.js](http://demo.st-marron.info/roulette/sample/demo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Para gerar o número aleatório no php use a função [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php), ela aceita dois argumentos o número incial e o final de um intervalo.

```
<?php
   $numero = rand(1 , 5);
   echo $numero;
```

O echo do número pode ser feito dentro (`value`) de um input hidden, assim o valor pode ser recuperado pelo javascript com `document.getElementById()`.

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/85RyEy)