# Dúvida Simples em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Bom a minha dúvida é relativamente simples, eu gostaria de saber como faria em Javascript que se uma condição verdadeira, por exemplo, `2 > 1` em vez de aparecer a imagem do `img` aparecesse a imagem do código em *script*.

Meu código:

```js
if(2>1){ document.getElementById("amarelo5").src = "cores-roleta/amarelo1.png";

}
```

```html
<img id="amarelo5" src="cores-roleta/amarelo0.png">
```

Comment: Dessa forma que você fez não está funcionando?

Comment: Infelizmente não.

Comment: Qual erro apresenta?

Comment: Continua a mostrar imagem amarelo0

Comment: Da uma olhada no console do navegador, qual erro apresenta?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como posso fazer uma roleta em Javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69620/como-posso-fazer-uma-roleta-em-javascript)

Comment: Exato, eu tinha colocado essa dúvida primeiro, mas agora que comecei a raciocinar, Vou tentar fazer as cores aparecerem seguidas até chegar a aquela cor.

Comment: Dá-me esse erro: http://prntscr.com/7hvwou

Comment: Clica em cima daquele `teste.html:3` que está no canto direito, ele vai ir direto pra linha com erro e manda um print dnv

Comment: Aqui está: http://prntscr.com/7hvy1n

Comment: Apesar de você não ter mostrado toda a tela, da pra ver que você está atribuindo no `innerHTML` e não no `src`, além desse erro não sei qual o resto por não ver até o final

Comment: Eu tentei com src e inner e ambos nao funcionam.

Comment: Neste exemplo que está na sua pergunta está funcionando normal, deve ser algum erro a mais que ficou ocultado, dê uma analisada.

Comment: Eu tentei com src e não funcionou também. http://prntscr.com/7hvz1r

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que seu script está executando antes da página terminar de ser carregada, para executar somente quando terminou faça isso:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(2>1){ 
        document.getElementById("amarelo5").src = "cores-roleta/amarelo1.png";
    }
}
```

Exemplo mudando a cor do `label` a cada 5 segundos, adapte conforme sua necessidade. A função pra ficar chamando a cada tempo é o `setInterval` e você informa em milissegundos.

```js
var cores = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
var contador = 0;
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById('tst').style.color = cores[contador % cores.length];
        contador++;
    }, 5000); // 5 segundos
}
```

```html
<label id="tst">Exemplo cores</label>
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!, Já agora diga-me uma coisa, se eu quiser fazer com q passado 5 segundos apareça a imagem laranja2 como eu faria? Ou seja como faria para que passada 5 segundos aparecesse outra imagem.

Comment: Ou seja, esperar 5 segundos, mudar de cor, esperar outros 5 mudar de cor dnv. etc...

Comment: @Gonçalo Alterei minha resposta com um exemplo pra você, não fiz exatamente o que você precisa porque quero que tu entenda e aprenda, mas a ideia é basicamente essa.

Comment: Bom, eu etendi a ideia, mas no caso eu queria alterar a imagem, de ids diferentes de 5 em 5 segundos, ou seja altero a imagem de id x, passado 5 segundos altero imagem de id y. Antes de mais obrigado por esta grande ajuda.